# ABS Tab navigation break randomly

Tags: android, tabs, styles, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ABS Tab navigation on Android 2.3.3 and experience this behavior in a random fashion. It could happen when I start this activity or rotate the device. You can see the difference in the images below.

[image: Normal Tab] [image: Bugged Tab]

I set theme using xml by doing the following.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".JobListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_job_list"
        android:theme="@style/OverallTheme" >
    </activity>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="OverallTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
</style>
```

I also overridePendingTransition of the activity and sometime it display this for a brief period:

[image: loading]

The strange thing is that, if this blocky view is displayed, the tab will displayed just fine. However, if it doesn't the style seems to appear in random manner. The images are from the same code running on Xperia Active. Any idea what I did wrong?

P.S. I am including HoloEveryWhere in this project as well but I did not use it as it turn the whole content area pitch black while every item can still be activate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that inside the Activity's onCreate I have

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

Removing this solve the problem.